# why logs are not visible for Dataflow job pipeline written in java sdk at GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-logging

I have enabled the logging API by below command :

```
gcloud services enable logging
```

I have followed the steps: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/create-pipeline-java to create the pipeline.

I am using slf4j logger lib for logging the jobs. still, no logs are visible in GCP dataflow console.

[image]

Comment: You also have empty logs in the `WORKER LOGS` tab ?

Comment: Hi @Siddhanta Rath, Did the below answer help you in resolving the issue?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT no, it didn't solve my issue

Comment: @MazlumTosun Yes, no worker logs as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new sink in Logs Router with an inclusion filter of `resource.type="dataflow_step"` solved the issue
as dataflow logs are excluded in the default sink present at the log router under logging.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a service account?
Besides enabling the Logging service, you may not have permission to write the the logs.

If that is the case, please double-check if you are following all the instructions from [Security and permissions for pipelines on Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#permissions).

Comment: yes, I am using a service account with all the permission. Still, no logs are visible UI.